# Preprocessed var not being passed to twig template

Tags: theming

I created a custom theme called wdocs as a sub theme of d8w3css. I made a template to override the menu template for the user account menu, calling it **menu--account.html.twig**. For my theme, I added the function `wdocs_preprocess_menu__account()` to my **wdocs.theme** file, and introduced a new variable with `$variables['tollfree_number'] = '555-1212'`; So far so good; in phpStorm I can set a breakpoint there are do see it is getting set in $variables. In my twig, I have some text, followed by `{{ tollfree_number }}`. The text gets displayed, but not the variable.

The problem is the twig calls a macro; I can access the var outside of the macro, but not within it. Googling suggested I pass context when calling the macro, so I changed the call to

```
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name, _context) }}
```

I also tried "context" (no underscore). And also tried dereferencing it with `{{ _context['tollfree_number'] }}`, but nothing seems to help. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You would need to change the macro definition as well. Or simply put the variable in an item below $variables['items'] and then display it: {{ item.foo }}

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in thinking that trying to access your var from within the macro is the issue. See [Twig's macro documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html).

> But as with PHP functions, macros don’t have access to the current template variables.

You can pass your variable into the macro.

```
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name, tollfree_number) }}
```

Then you have two options, you can update the macro definition to add an extra parameter for your custom var.

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name, toll_free) %}
  {# etc.. #}
  {{ toll_free }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Or you can use the special varargs variable without updating the macro definition.

> If extra positional arguments are passed to a macro, they end up in the special `varargs` variable as a list of values.

Pass the var to the macro the same way, then access it like:

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name) %}
  {# varargs[0] has the first extra arg, varargs[1] has the second, etc #}
  {{ varargs[0] }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Using the special `_context` and `varargs` vars:

```
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name, _context) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name) %}
  {{ varargs[0].tollfree_number }}
{% endmacro %}
```